# Optimization of LookUp like LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a complex Query.

I want to check if an item exists inside a `List (softwareLicencesList)` based on Key and value. However the data inside the `softwareLicencesList` is Encrypted. So first I want to decrypt it and then do a lookup inside a `Dictionary (dict)` to get the mapped value and then verify the mapped value against the `hardwareInfo Keys` `(hardwareInfo is a Dictionary which stores machine hardware information)`. Once the Key is verified then I want to match the value.

I wrote the following piece of code to do this. Well this code works but I would like to know if it can be optimized further.

```
  foreach (var i in hardwareInfo)
  {
       if (!softwareLicencesList.Exists(x => dict.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Key == Crypt.Decrypt(x.Key, "Encryption Key")).Value == i.Key
            && Crypt.VerifyHash(i.Value, "MD5", x.Value)))
             {
               //Do Something
             }
 }
```

The process of decrypting `Crypt.Decrypt()` and verifying Hash `Crypt.VerifyHash()` is complex. So I want to minimize the number of calls made to these functions.

Comment: why you are decrypting the entire list? encrypt your key and search for it in list instead

Comment: Your comment gave me an idea to keep encrypted values inside dict Dictionary for mapping. So... In this way I will save the time required for decryption and can directly map the encrypted keys present inside the Dictionary.

Thanks a lot!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the performance several places in your code. You use `FirstOrDefault` to find a value in a dictionary matching a specified key but the whole point of using a dictionary is that you in constant time can look up a value for a specified key. Also, you do not need to decrypt the software license key inside the dual nested loops. That is very inefficient.

So to improve your code you can build a list of software licenses with decrypted keys:

```
var decryptedSoftwareLicenses = softwareLicenses
  .Select(softwareLicense =>
    new {
      DecryptedKey = Crypt.Decrypt(softwareLicense.Key, "Encryption key"),
      SoftwareLicense = softwareLicense
    }
  )
  .ToList();
```

You can then build a LINQ expression to create your results:

```
var results = hardwareInfos
  .Where(hardwareInfo =>
    !decryptedSoftwareLicenses.Any(
      decrypted =>
        dictionary[decrypted.DecryptedKey] == hardwareInfo.Key
        && Crypt.VerifyHash(hardwareInfo.Value, "MD5", decrypted.SoftwareLicense.Value)
    )
  );
```

You can iterate `results` using `foreach` or apply `ToList` to perform the actual computation.

Notice that I changed the variable names from `i`, `x` and `y` to something more descriptive. Your choice of names makes it really hard to understand your code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation!! 
And going forward I will make sure to following better programming conventions.